# love2d sprites remove background from image

Tags: lua, love2d

[so for every character that I add a sprite, they end up like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVf9Y.png)

I've tried with different images, all png. only one seems to work fine and not have a background square but can't figure out why. also thought of generating the characters sprites first and then the map which worked horribly because the map covered everything.

I'm building a basic game, mixing tutorials, even in those sprites that they use, I still have the background square and they don't, I assume I'm making a really dumb mistake.

Comment: If you do not want a white background, do not add a white background. In your paint software, get rid of it and save with a format supporting the alpha channel (e.g. png). Love2d by default has proper alpha blending enabled.

Comment: After a zoom I notices that the white background is actually a transparency pattern which usually occurs if you copy it from e.g. google and its a jpeg in disguise.

Comment: I bet @Luke100000 is right - So load your PNG in GIMP and delete the white Background to transparency - Dont forget to save it over/as original PNG - Also i suggest to try some of the thousands of free Assets available out there in between ;-)

Comment: yeah, jpeg in disguise was the issue, thanks.